# How migrate moment.updateLocale() to date-fns locale method?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, javascript-objects, moment-timezone, date-fns

Here is my code snap for more details:

index.js

```
import moment from 'moment'

moment.updateLocale('en', {
  relativeTime: {
    future: 'in %s',
    past: '%s ago',
    s: '%ds',
    m: '%dm',
    mm: '%dm',
    h: '%dh',
    hh: '%dh',
    d: '%dd',
    dd: '%dd',
    M: '%d month',
    MM: '%d months',
    y: '%d year',
    yy: '%d years'
  }
})

function format ({ duration }) {
  // How to return below output from date-fns module?
  return moment.duration(duration).humanize()
}

console.log(format(60000))// output is -->  10m
```

`cmd> node index.js`

The same thing I wanted to do through date-fns local. But I did not see any updateLocale method and not sure how to do the mapping. which I did in moment.updateLocale({}) object.

Answer (score 0):

After spending quality time found a workaround for this problem. The problem is date-fns formateDuration() is not providing support for mapping the synonyms for duration passed. So defined the workaround for this problem. until date-fns people fix this problem. replace the below code to your it will give the same result.

```
import { intervalToDuration, formatDuration } from 'date-fns'
// work around, until it fixed by date-fns libraray formatDuration method
const formatDistanceLocale = { xSeconds: '{{count}}s', xMinutes: '{{count}}m', xHours: '{{count}}h' }
const shortEnLocale = { formatDistance: (token, count) => formatDistanceLocale[token].replace('{{count}}', count) }

export function format ({ duration }) {
  duration = intervalToDuration({ start: 0, end: duration })
  return formatDuration(duration, { format: ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'], locale: shortEnLocale })
}
```